# Can you convert/build a docker image into a full OS image?

Tags: image, docker, operating-system, debian, iso

I have made a docker container meant with some code for deployment. However, I realised that the structure of the project I'm working with, it's more suitable to deploy a full ISO image, instead of running docker on top of a cloud VM running stock debian, leading to unnecessary layers of virtualization.

I know that dockers are meant to be deployed on kubernetes, but before diving into that route, is there a simple way to convert a deb9 docker image into a full deb9 OS image? Like an opposite of `docker import`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can convert your docker **container** to an full os image. An Dockerfile debian example would be

```
FROM debian:stretch
RUN apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends \
  linux-image-amd64 \
  systemd-sysv
```

In principal you have to install a kernel and an init system.

Full instructions can be found [github](https://github.com/iximiuz/docker-to-linux)

Answer (score 3):

Docker images don't contain a Linux kernel and aren't configured to do things like run a full init system or go out and get their network configuration, so this won't work well.

Put differently: the same mismatch that makes `docker import` not really work well because the resulting container will have too much stuff and won't be set up for Docker, means you can't export a container or image into a VM and expect it to work in that environment.

But!  If you've written a Dockerfile for your image, that's very close to saying "I'm going to start from this base Linux distribution and run this shell script to get an image".  Tools like [Packer](https://packer.io/) are set up to take a base Linux VM image, run some sort of provisioner, and create a new image.  If you have a good Docker setup already, and decide a VM is a better fit, you're probably done a lot of the leg-work already to have an automated build of your VM image.

Comment: Instead of using the dockerfile to install programs when the container 'boots', I manually installed programs and then committed the whole container. So I'm basically out of luck?